# Hamachi VPN client Raspberry Pi disconnecting?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hamachi

Ok, so I have one of two (or both) problems occurring and I can't for the life of me solve it. First, I have a raspberry pi running raspbian wheezy on my home lan (connected via ethernet) and it's running headless. I set up a VPN using hamachi and got my pi and another computer connected to it, no problem. Now, I moved the raspberry pi to a different lan (same 192.168.1.x setup). I can connect to the pi locally so I know the static ip is still set, but hamachi doesn't see it in the VPN? Also, when it does work, the raspberry pi goes offline in about 10 minutes (I checked the led's, the whole interface just goes down, even if I'm currently using ssh). Does anyone know what's going on, or why it doesn't show up in the VPN once I move to a different LAN than the one I set it up on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my windows computer.
After a few google searches I discovered this site with a solution for a windows computer. Anyhow let me know if you have the same solution for your raspberry pi because I'm planning to buy one ;-).

Here you find more information and a solution for windows:
http://chattim.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/hamachi-keeps-disconnecting-after-closing-rdp-session-solved-fix/